# Shoulder blade protraction during rotator cuff internal/external rotations

Tags: back-pain, physical-therapy

Two important exercises used to treat shoulder instability and impingement are internal and external rotator cuff rotations, which can be done bearing weight via exercise bands. The upper arm is to be kept approximately parallel with the torso during rotation, so as to avoid engagement of the deltoids or pecs.

Despite various sources demonstrating the exercise, there is a subtle point that is rarely addressed: what is the proper placement of the shoulder blade during these exercises? In particular, there are two states:

(1) Protract the shoulder blade by engaging the serratus anterior.
or
(2) Retract the shoulder blade by engaging the rhomboids.

How should we position the shoulder blade during these two very fundamental physical therapy exercises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should retract the shoulder blades (at least for external rotation) (1: 9mins).
For someone that is not experiencing shoulder pain I think it may suffice to do windmills or Turkish get ups (2). These also train the rotator cuffs (3).

An interesting (?) curiosity is that we are the only specie that can throw really hard and really fast.
Throwing probably played an important part in human evolution. The rotator cuffs are used to load up the shoulders with elastic energy when bringing the object being thrown up and behind the head (4).

(1) [Improving Rotator Cuff Strength & Stability](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7R-cZYyhtI0)

(2) [Build STRONG shoulders (2 GREAT Exercises!)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COmMMqlCsa4)

(3) [How to Kettlebell Windmill + Anatomical Analysis](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=772096266657936)

(4) [Mechanics of Throwing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_bYlY6AHew)